# Next.js can not load JSX files via custom .babelrc configuartion

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

I am trying to use the .jsx file type and have created a custom .babelrc file as per the Next.js documentation (see below). https://github.com/zeit/next.js#customizing-babel-config

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "extensions": [".jsx"]
    }]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

However with the above .babelrc file I receive the following error:

[image: The error I am seeing.]

Can someone point me in the direction as to what I am doing wrong to get jsx files to load properly?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Next.js has [support for `.jsx` files](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/3376) out of the box. There should be no need to customize your `.babelrc`, so you can either use the default one or just delete it altogether.

Make sure you are running the latest version of Next.js, and possibly delete the `node_modules` and the `.next` folder in your project directory. Then install the dependencies again & build.

Comment: Hey when I started this project the JSX support wasn't built in yet. Had to end up using a pre-release of their package. Thanks for the help!